# socket.io client, doesn't emit message to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');


onClickEvent -> io.emit('test', 'testMessage');
```

I have this code. On click I'm emitting data to server.
When I'm clicking to emit, from tab#1, it emitting properly.
But When I'm clicking from tab #2, it doesn't emitting.

there is not any error, in console...

In both tabs, messages from server comes with no problem, but there is something wrong during emitting from client to server.

any idea?

Comment: first off, no reason to use socket.io, use primus, or express.ws, 2 the problem is probably in your click event binding check if your click event fires on the second tab.

Comment: there is no problem in click event. click events fires, but doesn't emit

Comment: Well you have the code and you can't figure it out and you expect that we figure it out with just two lines of code? You definitely  need to add more code.

Comment: try to use `socket.emit` instead of `io.emit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work using:

```
socket.emit('test', 'testMessage');
```